# How delete from array all same elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I delete all same elements from array if
for exsample I have 
`var arr = [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];`
I need to get array like this 
`[2,3,4,5,6,7];`
I' using this

```
var chotch = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < text1_arr.length; i++) {
    if(word1_reg.test(text1_arr[i])) {
       text1_arr.splice(i, 1);
       chotch++;
       if(needCount === chotch) {
          break;
       }
     } else {
        continue;
     }
 }
```

Comment: What code have you written while attempting to answer your own question? It is better to have written code and paste it here for people to see what you have attempted rather than just asking for the answer

Comment: To clarify, when delete all same elements, you do not want to retain an original copy? So if you see more than one copy of an element, you want to remove the element entirely?

Comment: There's everything you need in my answer. Good night.

Answer (score 1):

Following code returns array just elements which occurs **only** once.

**ES6** solution.

```js
var arr = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5];

(function cleanIt(arr) {
  var arr2 = arr.filter((v, i) => arr.indexOf(v) != i);
  var newArr = arr.filter(v => !arr2.includes(v));
  
  console.log(newArr);
  console.log(`Elements deleted: ${arr.length-newArr.length}`);
})(arr);
```

**ES5** solution. **Note**: `Array#includes` is ES6 feature.

```js
var arr = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5];

(function cleanIt(arr) {
  var arr2 = arr.filter(function(v,i) {
    return arr.indexOf(v) != i;
  });
  var newArr = arr.filter(function(v) {
    return !arr2.includes(v);
  });

  console.log(newArr);
  console.log('Elements deleted: ' + (arr.length - newArr.length));
})(arr);
```

Comment: Works fine, upvoted. It'd be perfect if you add ES5 version of it.

Comment: FYI, [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function is not ES5-compliant.

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim True. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDuplicates(input){
  var out = [];
  var duplicates = [];
  input.forEach(function(item){
    if(duplicates.indexOf(item)!==-1)return;
    var outIndex = out.indexOf(item)
    if(outIndex!==-1){
      out.splice(outIndex,1)
      duplicates.push(item);
      return;
    }
    out.push(item)
  });
  return out;
}
removeDuplicates([1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) // [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: It works too, but a lot of code here though. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your array and check for every item that it exists only once using use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf). If yes, then add it to a result array.

```
var arr = [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if (arr.indexOf(arr[i]) === arr.lastIndexOf(arr[i])) {
       result.push(arr[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: I must delete and everytime count that for example  var chotch = 0;                                         for(var i = 0; i < text1_arr.length; i++) {
     if(word1_reg.test(text1_arr[i])) {
     text1_arr.splice(i, 1);
     chotch++;
         if(needCount === chotch) {
              break;
         }
     } else {
          continue;
     }
}

Comment: @David no, you are not deleting anything, you just push unique items into another array.

Comment: @Ahmad: I'm understanding what you mean but I need to delete and count how many element's deleted

Comment: @David you can compare the length of the two arrays to get how many items were deleted (i.e. `arr.length  - result.length`). And to delete them from the original array you can just replace it `arr = result;`

Comment: @David it's not clear what this code has to do with your question. It'd be better if you state clearly what you're trying to do, and what're `text1_arr`, `word1_reg`, `needCount`.. etc.

Comment: text1_arr is an array which elements are sentences, I need to delete that sentences wich contain the word that I want So if I have 5 sentences and 3 from them contain that word and I want 1 sentenc wich will contain that word I must to delete ather 2 sentences which are contain the word

Answer (score 0):

This strategy eliminates any element that can be found 2 times.

```js
const arr = [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
const uniqs = a => a.filter(e => a.slice(a.indexOf(e) + 1).indexOf(e) === -1);
console.log(uniqs(arr));
```